# How can I create a dynamic Select statement within a SQL Select statement?

Tags: sql, dynamic

I have a `SELECT` statement that can produce a list of values:

```
DECLARE @ValueList varchar(Max);

SELECT @ValueList = COALESCE(@ValueList + ',', '') + CAST(Val AS varchar(max))
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT tblSampleTable.SomeIDNumber AS Val 
     FROM tblSampleTable) AS ValuesThisYear

PRINT @ValList
```

This returns a list with values something like

```
val1,val2,val4,val9,
```

etc., ehich I can then feed into a stored procedure, or manage some other way.

Now I want to have the query that gets assessed for the list of values to be dynamic, maybe passed in or from another stored procedure, similar to this:

```
DECLARE @ValueList varchar(Max);
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(Max);

SET @TSQL = {stored proc to get base query}

SELECT @ValueList = COALESCE(@ValueList + ',', '') + CAST(Val AS varchar(max))
FROM 
    (@TSQL) AS ValuesThisYear

PRINT @ValList
```

I know that's the wrong syntax for including `@TSQL`, and that's what I'm trying to find out. I've viewed a number of threads and tried a number of methods, but am still not able to incorporate this dynamic part.

The tricky part seems to be the making of the list (the `COALESCE` and `CAST` statements), where I incorporate `@ValList` as part of the returned string.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic SQL is usually about

- Creating a variable that contains the exact SQL you want to run
- Then using EXEC (@SQLvariable) to run that code

For example (not for production yet!) I've added a new variable @CustomSQL

```
DECLARE @ValueList varchar(Max);
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(Max);
DECLARE @CustomSQL varchar(Max);

SET @TSQL = {stored proc to get base query}

SET @CustomSQL =
    'SELECT COALESCE(@ValueList + '','', '''') + CAST(Val AS varchar(max))
     FROM (
          ' + @TSQL + '
          ) As ValuesThisYear;'

PRINT @CustomSQL
EXEC (@CustomSQL)
```

Notice that adding text/strings (e.g., the @TSQL variable) have to be entered as exact strings rather than their variable names. Also note apostrophes - you need to use '' every time you wish to refer to a '.

I also removed the variable name from the `SELECT @ValueList = ...` because the dynamic SQL cannot actually reference the variables - it has its own scope (?cannot remember the correct word) and doesn't have access to the variables. Solutions to this include

- Using a temporary table e.g., #temp  which *can* be referenced
- Using the OUTPUT clause

Personally, I would approach it a different way - use the T-Sql provided to put data into a temporary table. Then use the temporary table in the other statement e.g.,

```
DECLARE @ValueList varchar(Max);
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(Max);
SET @TSQL = {stored proc to get base query}

DECLARE @CustomSQL varchar(Max)
CREATE TABLE #temp (Val varchar(1000))
SET @CustomSQL = 'INSERT INTO #temp (Val) ' + @TSQL
EXEC (@CustomSQL)

SELECT @ValueList = COALESCE(@ValueList + ',', '') + CAST(Val AS varchar(max))
FROM #temp As ValuesThisYear;
PRINT @ValList
```

I almost never get my dynamic SQL correct first try. Suggestions

- Keep it as simple as possible
- Before having a version that runs (e.g., EXEC (@CustomSQL)), comment the EXEC out and PRINT it instead.

Here are some examples from previous posts I've done recently

- [Query for R Machine Learning Services - Filtering Categories in Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141841/query-for-r-machine-learning-services-filtering-categories-in-where-clause/64142408#64142408)
- Bottom of [Dynamic columns depend on previous dynamic columns - TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183595/dynamic-columns-depend-on-previous-dynamic-columns-tsql/64185008#64185008)

Comment: Perfect.  Was thinking that I could just place the text for the sql in there, but a temp table works great.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it helped.